# Sum of Functions with Incommensurable Periods

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I am trying, essentially, to prove that for incommensurable numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, and some $\epsilon > 0$, there exist integers $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|na + mb| < \epsilon$.

There are several other problems equivalent or very closely related to this. For example, a ray with irrational slopes under the quotient map $\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$ is dense, or the fact that $(-n, n) \subseteq Im(\sin a_1x + \dots + \sin a_nx)$ where $a_1 \dots a_n$ all incommensurable. I have seen similar questions posted in the following StackOverflow entries, but they are always solved without justification. I am trying to actually prove that these facts are true (they will mostly imply each other).

[Minimum of sum of incommensurable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595294/minimum-of-sum-of-incommensurable-functions)

[Period of the sum/product of two functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions)

[Range of a sum of sine waves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52352/range-of-a-sum-of-sine-waves)

It seems like the result is well known, so I assume I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Note that the inequality holds trivially when $n=m=0$, so you have to say $0<|na+mb| <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $b$ is irrational. I will first prove the result when $a=1$. For each positive integer $m$ there exists a unique integer $n_m$ in the interval $[-mb,-mb+1)$. Let $x_m=n_m+mb$ so $x_m \in [0,1)$ for each $m$. Choose a positive integer $k$ such that $\frac 1 k <\epsilon$. Consider the number $x_1,x_2,...,x_{k+1}$ in $[0,1)$. If any two of these differ by $\frac 1 k$ or more then the difference between the largest and the smallest of them would exceed $1$ which is a contradiction. In other words there exist $i,j$ such that $0<|x_i-x_j| <\frac 1 k <\epsilon$.  Thus $0<|(n_i+ib)-(n_j+jb)| <\epsilon$. [The fact that $b$ is irrational is required to say that $(n_i+ib)-(n_j+jb) \neq 0]$.  This proves the result when $a=1$. A simple modification gives the result for any $a$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.